# Draw on top of other OpenGL / DX application using Java

Tags: java, opengl, directx

Is there some way to draw on top of other application that working in OpenGl (DirectX) full-screen mode using Java?

Answer (score 0):

There're bindings for Java, that may suit your requirements: http://swogl.javagl.de/ e.g..